# changing text AND showing an additional div depending on checkbox checked in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hide, show

I've been searching everywhere for the past few hours so this is my last hope! I have a form which has a checkbox and below I have a text input with the description besides it saying "Your Name". I want to change it so that when someone checks the form, it will change the description besides the text input to "Your Nickname" instead of "Your Name".

In addition, if the checkbox is checked, it also needs to show a hidden div below the form with more content. Likewise, if the box is unchecked again, it should go back to "Your Name" again as well as hide the div again.

I will gladly name my first born child after you if you can help me! lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give me the code - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CCppk/) it is-

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxId" name="checkName" />
    <br/>
    <span id="description">Your Name </span>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <br/>
    <div id="moreContentId" style="display: none;"> Here goes some more content ! </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#checkBoxId").click( function() {

     if($("#checkBoxId").is(":checked")) {
        /*When the checkbox is checked*/
        $("#description").html("Your Nickname"); //change the description
        $("#moreContentId").show(); // show some content
    }
    else {
        /*When the checkbox is not checked*/
        $("#description").html("Your Name"); // revert back the description
        $("#moreContentId").hide(); // hide the content
    }
});
```